# How to connect to a Service on iOS?

Tags: ios, xpc

I am new to XPC and do not have much background in programming. Suppose there is a service "com.apple.geod" or other services on iOS devices. Is it possible to write a simple iOS application that connects to them? If yes, how can it be done? Can someone provide some simple code snippet?

I tried various online sources to connect to it but I get `Connection invalid` message, or the online resource is meant for MacOS.

Below snippet is based on https://medium.com/@theninjaprawn/breaking-ios-xpc-cfe2c3083c87

```
    #define NAME "com.apple.geod"
    ....
    xpc_connection_t conn = xpc_connection_create_mach_service(NAME, NULL, 0);
    xpc_connection_set_event_handler(conn, ^(xpc_object_t object) {
    NSLog(@"Event: %@", object);
    });

    xpc_connection_resume(conn);
```

References

- https://medium.com/@ali.pourhadi/fun-with-xpc-153fd772d409
- https://8ksec.io/advanced-frida-usage-part-3-inspecting-ios-xpc-calls/
- https://medium.com/@theninjaprawn/breaking-ios-xpc-cfe2c3083c87